# Using numpy, javascript, and django

Tags: javascript, python, django, numpy

I am trying to create a web app using django, and integrating some javascript and i'm not sure where to put the numpy analysis to allow javascript to access the data easily.

I am just looking for some advice on where to put my data analysis code within the django framework. At the moment I have got a model/form for people to enter data, and within views.py I have access the inputs and done the calculation (creating a dataframe) there. Still within the views, I have created a graph (using matplotlib) that saves as an image that my html reads in.

I am not happy with the graph that is being created, so I want to use chart.js for this instead. However I am not sure on the best way to go about structuring this. Should I keep the calculations within the views class, or is it best to move it out? I have looked at using the django rest framework, but I am having difficulty getting the dataframe that I created in my view for the javascript to read.

Has anyone done a similar thing or has any advice on how to go about setting this up?

Comment: Where are you put your html and js code now? In a template file?

Comment: Yes, I have template files for the html and js code. It is just getting the dataframe from the python(django) code in a format where the html/js can read it.